# How to change post name permalink in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a Wordpress website, and the current URL link to access the post page is `http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/sample-post/`. After several changes I moved the wordpress folder, so I want to change the URL link into `http://localhost/wordpress/sample-post/` (no double /wordpress). The problem is Wordpress doesn't allow me to change the permalink in the permalink settings menu. I have attached the screenshot of the menu below.

[Wordpress Permalink Settings Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcuYH.png)

Are there any alternatives to change it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your database, to see if home and site url has `http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/` might even be defined in the htaccess file - it's the first two rows in `wp_options` table, also found in wordpress settings under general

Comment: Thankyou so much @Stender , your solution works! Didn't notice there is a menu for changing it in the settings.